# Expected value to get all possible outcomes for coin flipping trials

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Consider the experiment where we keep flipping two fair coins. If the random variable X is defined to be the number of trials to get all possible outcomes, find E(X) and Var(X). Since the coins are distinct (H,T) and (T,H) would count as distinct outcomes.

I've been trying to think about a solution to this problem by possibly defining X in terms of 4 different random variables representing the expected number of trials for each individual outcome. I don't know how I would structure this solution however, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Answer (score 0):

#### For one coin

Let's call the number of flips as $n$.

$$
P(X=1) = 0 \\
P(X=n) = \dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}; n = 2,3,\cdots
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}[X] &= \sum_{n=2} n\times P(n) = \sum_{n=2} \dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}} = 3 \\
\text{var}[X] &= \text{E}[X^2] - \text{E}[X]^2 \\
&= \sum_{n=2} n^2\times P(n) - 3^2 \\
&= \sum_{n=2} \dfrac{n^2}{2^{n-1}} - 9 \\
&= 2 \\
\end{align}
$$

#### For two coins

Let's call the number of flips of the first and second coin together as $n$.

$$
P(X = 1,2,3) = 0 \\
P(X = n) = \dfrac{3}{4^{n-3}}, n = 4,5,6,\cdots
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}[X] &= \sum_{n=4} n\times P(n) = \sum_{n=2} \dfrac{3n}{4^{n-3}} = \dfrac{13}{3} \\
\text{var}[X] &= \text{E}[X^2] - \text{E}[X]^2 \\
&= \sum_{n=4} n^2\times P(n) - \left( \dfrac{13}{3} \right) ^2 \\
&= \sum_{n=4} \dfrac{3n^2}{4^{n-3}} - \dfrac{169}{9} \\
&= \dfrac{4}{9} \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I must not understand your notation or calculation, because your result for $E[X]$ makes no sense.  We're flipping two fair coins.  As the OP states, (H,T) differs from (T,H)... and of course from (H,H) and (T,T).  At *minimum* (best case scenario), we need FOUR tries to get all four configurations.  But you say the AVERAGE is 7/3.  Please explain.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I updated the answer, does it explain now?

Comment: Ahhh.... THAT now makes sense.  ($+1$). Thanks.